# Junit 5 test cases are not executing in gradle 4.4

Tags: gradle, junit

My junit 5 test cases are not executing.
Can anyone suggest some solution?
Gradle version is 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need [Gradle 4.6 or later](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html) to get support for JUnit 5.

Once you upgrade Gradle, be sure to configure it for JUnit 5. See the [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5) for details. For example:

```java
// build.gradle (Groovy DSL)
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```